# How to say 'OR' in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
name = afunction('thing1'.trim());
```

What I want is to trim `thing1` or `thing2` or `thing3` (whichever is available). How to do it?
I tried with ||, OR and comma. None of them worked.

Comment: show your tried code. || is worked for javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a variable:

```
var item = "thing1" || "thing2"; // or assign with a ternary operation.
name = afunction(item.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

|| [should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/k7wegcq2/).

```
var thing1 = null;
var thing2 = undefined;
var thing3= "Thing 3 ";

alert( (thing1||thing2||thing3).trim());

//Test 2 

thing1 = "";
thing2 = "Thing 2 ";
var thing3= "Thing 3 ";

alert( (thing1||thing2||thing3).trim());
```